# Lerna Detached git HEAD error in Azure devOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, lerna

In my pipeline, I just simply did the following in one of my steps

```
lerna publish --yes
```

And I received error

```
lerna ERR! ENOGIT Detached git HEAD, please checkout a branch to choose versions.
```

I think it probably be something trivial, really appreciated for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong -- the default behavior of pipelines is to checkout a commit, not a branch, thus detaching `HEAD`. I'm not familiar with Lerna or what "publish" does, so I can't tell you if what you're trying to do is going to be a bad idea or not, but you can simply `checkout` the appropriate branch before running the command.